# solid state relay unexpected behavior

Tags: solid-state-relay

I've wired a `teledyne s24d40` ssr to a `leviton 20 amp duplex outlet` using a 12 gauge extension cord.

The load is a 1200 watt wagner heat gun and I'm using a 9v battery to test.

This is my first AC project and I'm trying to make sure I haven't done something incorrectly.

ext cord green ground wire -> outlet green earth terminal
ext cord neutral white wire -> outlet silver terminal
ext cord hot black wire -> ssr output terminal 1
ssr output terminal 2 -> outlet brass terminal
+/- wires to ssr control terminals

When the ssr is triggered and the heat gun power switch is set to `high`, everything works as expected.

However, when the ssr is triggered with the heat gun power switch set to `low`, the heat gun does not power on.

Can anyone explain what's going on? I need to use the heat gun in the `low` setting for this application.

I apologize if this is an ignorant question, I'm still learning :)

Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: Draw a simple schematics with schematics editor included in this forum. Add link to datasheet to SSR and heatgun.  How can we know what your heat gun does?

Comment: Looking at the datasheet, it seems like you're well inside the operating range. I would try connecting some other resistive type devices to the output.

Comment: The relay does require a minimum load of 5ma. Perhapse the heat gun has some internal circuitry that interferes with this minimum load? What happens if you hook a splitter up the the outlet, and connect a lightbulb or similar in parallel with the heat gun?

Comment: @Drew You're correct. The circuit in the heat gun switch does *not* draw any current when first powered, if set to `low`. It does start drawing current if set to `high`. 

So I tried your suggestion of hooking up a splitter with a lightbulb and the ssr turned the heat gun on when set to `low`.

Is there a way I can mark your comment as the answer to this question?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll copy it to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relay requires a minimum load of 5ma. Perhaps the heat gun has some internal circuitry that interferes with this minimum load? If you hook up a splitter to the outlet and connect a lightbulb or similar in parallel with the heatgun that may solve the problem.